how to create react elements with independent state when mapping through an array
my component structure looks like app/dashboard. Dashboard is the parent component of ResumeForm and Resume. The Dashboard holds the state and is passed down as props to both components. In ResumeForm I have 3 nested components. I want to dynamically display an ExperienceForm(1 of the 3nested components) to display another form if user . The issue is when its displayed they all hold the same state since im passing it as props. how do i fix this issue?
export default function ResumeForm({
  basicInputs,
  setBasicInputsProps,

  experienceInputs,
  setExperienceInputsProps,

  eduInputs,
  setEduInputsProps,
  setShown,

  section,
  setSection,
}) {
  return (
    <form className="bg-indigo-300 w-2/5 h-[40rem] rounded-md p-5 overflow-auto">
      <h1 className="text-center py-4 font-bold text-5xl bg-gradient-to-r from-rose-100 to- teal-100 bg-clip-text text-transparent">
        CV Generator
      </h1>
      <BasicInfoForm
        basicInputs={basicInputs}
        setBasicInputsProps={setBasicInputsProps}
      />

      {section.map(() => (
        <ExperienceForm
          key={crypto.randomUUID()}
          experienceInputs={experienceInputs}
          setExperienceInputsProps={setExperienceInputsProps}
          setShown={setShown}
          setSection={setSection}
        />
      ))}

      <EducationalForm
        eduInputs={eduInputs}
        setEduInputsProps={setEduInputsProps}
      />
    </form>
  );
}


Create all the state you need in the ancestor component and pass down as props like you are, or move the states into the individual components that use it.

The elements render, but when I type inside inputs it shares the state with the other react elements as well

Right, because you have one state they all share. You should create state for all of them if you want to centralize it and pass it down.

Got it! thanks you!
